# How to normalize Futures data(different leverage) for cointegration test?

Tags: time-series, futures, cointegration

For example I want to construct 2 time series, one for ES and the other for NQ and test for cointegration.

ES one point equal to 50$.

NQ one point equal to 20$.

If I have the following data:

ES[0]=1300;ES[1]=1307;ES[2]=1314...

NQ[0]=2700;NQ[1]=2692;NQ[2]=2715...

How do I normalize this data for cointegration test?

TX in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiply each price series by its multiplier to get notional values.  Then proceed as if the notional value were the price of 1 share.

Answer (score 3):

In a co-integration test you rely on the original price series -- not transformations of the price series such as rate of change and so on. Seems to me there is no need for normalization.

Comment: A "normalization" can be a useful **nonlinear transformation** quite different from *differencing* (which should be generally avoided, as you suggest - unless one is dealing with higher order cointegration).

Comment: excellent point

Comment: but my problem quantGuy is that if you want to trade such a portfolio the different leverage of each instrument is not taken into account.What I think should be done is multiply the price by the point value and then look for cointegration. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: I see. Yes, that makes sense. Your assumption is that the notional value per @user508's point is stationary. You test for cointegration after adjusting for leverage.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to look at constant volatility series.  Just divide the returns by some volatility measure on each series respectively (e.g. ($r_t * volatilitytarget)/\sigma(50 days)$).  Then the change in one will be equivalent in size to the change in the other.